# Instantsearch v2 different hits in view and map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, algolia, instantsearch.js

We're using Instantsearch (`2.10.4`) with a custom places widget to display on a map and also results beneath the map.

The places widget code is this:

```
var placesWidget = {
    init: function(opts){

        var container = document.querySelector('#IS__radius');
        var radius = document.querySelector('#radiusSlider');

        var placesAutocomplete = places({
            container: container,
            templates: {
                value: function(suggestion) {
                    return suggestion.name;
                }
            }
        }).configure({
            type: 'city',
            aroundLatLngViaIP: false,
            useDeviceLocation: false,
        });;

        placesAutocomplete.on('change', function(e) {
            var location = e.suggestion;
            var lat = location.latlng['lat'];
            var lng = location.latlng['lng'];
            opts.helper.setQueryParameter('query', $('#IS__search').val());
            opts.helper.setQueryParameter('aroundLatLng', lat + ',' + lng);
            opts.helper.setQueryParameter('aroundRadius', parseInt($('#radiusSlider').val()));
            opts.helper.search();
        });

        container.addEventListener("input", onInputChange);
        function onInputChange(event) {
            if (event.currentTarget.value === "") {
                opts.helper.setQueryParameter("aroundLatLng");
                opts.helper.search();
            }
            if (event.currentTarget.value.length >= 2) {
                $('.searchbox__distri .rs__container').addClass('visible');
                $('.mapsContainer #hits').show();
            } else {
                $('.mapsContainer #hits').hide();
            }
        }

        $('button.ap-icon-clear').on('click', function(){
            $('.searchbox__distri .rs__container').removeClass('visible');
            $('.singleResult').slideUp(250).find('.viewer').html('');
            opts.helper.setQueryParameter("aroundLatLng");
            opts.helper.search();
        });

        enableRadiusSlider(opts);
    }
};
```

Initially, all markers seem to show correctly as well as the text results underneath the map. But the map results do not respect the places search input correctly, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

The 6 boxes below are correct, yet the map keeps showing way too many results (but not all).

The line within the render of the map (see below) `params.helper.setQueryParameter('query', $('#IS__search').val());` should take care of that, I thought. Debugging it gives me the correct value which should be taken.

```
map = {
    _mapContainer: document.querySelector('#map-instantsearch-container'),
    markers: [],

    _hitToMarker: function(hit) {

        var icon = {
            url: 'typo3conf/ext/siteway/Resources/Public/Images/markerclusterer/basePin@2x.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(39, 58),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(39, 58)
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat: hit._geoloc.lat,
                lng: hit._geoloc.lng
            },
            map: this._map,
            icon: icon,
            title: hit.company+' / '+hit.zip+' '+hit.city,
        });

        // trigger custom function on marker click
        window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            distriDetail(hit.objectID,this.position.lat(),this.position.lng());
        });

        return marker;
    },

    init: function(params) {

        radius = document.querySelector('#radius');

        this._helper = params.helper;

        // init the map
        this._map = new google.maps.Map(
            this._mapContainer,
            {
                zoom: 2,
                backgroundColor: "#eeeeee",
                styles: [{"elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#f5f5f5"}]},{"elementType": "labels.icon","stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},{"elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#616161"}]},{"elementType": "labels.text.stroke","stylers": [{"color": "#f5f5f5"}]},{"featureType": "administrative.land_parcel","elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#bdbdbd"}]},{"featureType": "poi","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#eeeeee"}]},{"featureType": "poi","elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#757575"}]},{"featureType": "poi.park","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#e5e5e5"}]},{"featureType": "poi.park","elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#9e9e9e"}]},{"featureType": "road","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#ffffff"}]},{"featureType": "road.arterial","elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#757575"}]},{"featureType": "road.highway","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#dadada"}]},{"featureType": "road.highway","elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#616161"}]},{"featureType": "road.local","elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#9e9e9e"}]},{"featureType": "transit.line","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#e5e5e5"}]},{"featureType": "transit.station","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#eeeeee"}]},{"featureType": "water","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#c9c9c9"}]},{"featureType": "water","elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#9e9e9e"}]}],
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.0964656, 5.9588265),
            }
        );
    },

    render: function(params)
    {
        console.log('render fn');
        console.log(params);
        params.helper.setQueryParameter('query', $('#IS__search').val());

        // clear markers
        this.markers.forEach(function (marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });

        // transform hits to Google Maps markers
        this.markers = params.results.hits.map(this._hitToMarker.bind(this));

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        // make sure we display the good part of the maps
        this.markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        });

        var clusterStyles = [
            {
                textColor: 'white',
                textSize: 15,
                anchor: [12, 39],
                url: 'typo3conf/ext/siteway/Resources/Public/Images/markerclusterer/basePin.png',
                height: 70,
                width: 39
            },
            {
                textColor: 'white',
                textSize: 15,
                anchor: [12, 39],
                url: 'typo3conf/ext/siteway/Resources/Public/Images/markerclusterer/basePin.png',
                height: 70,
                width: 39
            },
            {
                textColor: 'white',
                textSize: 15,
                anchor: [12, 39],
                url: 'typo3conf/ext/siteway/Resources/Public/Images/markerclusterer/basePin.png',
                height: 70,
                width: 39
            }
        ];

        var mcOptions = {
            gridSize: 58,
            styles: clusterStyles,
            maxZoom: 15
        };

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(this._map, this.markers, mcOptions);

        this._map.fitBounds(bounds);

        // zoom on results
        var zoom = this._map.getZoom();
        this._map.setZoom(zoom > 14 ? 14 : zoom);
    }
};
```

**Why does the map show different results than the hits template?** It does not make sense.

Comment: Could you provide an example? That would help to inspect the queries sent to Algolia. https://codesandbox.io/s/github/algolia/create-instantsearch-app/tree/templates/instantsearch.js-2.x

Comment: @SamuelVaillant https://codesandbox.io/s/0qn81q60pv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue comes from the `MarkerClusterer`. This is a stateful object so it keep the previous markers on the map. One possible solution is to create the cluster at the `init` step. At the `render` step you can clear the previous markers and attach the new ones on the cluster. Here is [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/64v0pjzwo3) that shows how to do it.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks so much. :)